# Why can an event on the upper sheet of the timelike hyperboloid never be transformed onto the lower one?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

Currently reading about special relativity in Griffiths E&M, more specifically the invariant interval between two events. Suppose just two spatial dimensions $x$ and $y$ and a temporal dimension $t$. If one event is set to the origin, then the locus of all points in the Minkowski diagram with the same timelike interval $I \equiv -c^2 t^2 + x^2 + y^2 < 0$ will be a hyperboloid with an "upper sheet" and a "lower sheet".

[image]

Now the author claims that any point on the upper sheet can be carried to any other point on the upper sheet by Lorentz transformation, since $I$ is invariant under Lorentz transformations. However, he claims that no point on the upper sheet can ever to Lorentz transformed onto the lower sheet, thereby saving the principle of causality (since all observers will have to agree on the order between two events, when the interval is timelike and they are able to interact). Is there any way to prove this inability to bring a point on the upper sheet to the lower sheet, which is so important to causality? It certainly does not violate the invariance of $I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the upper hyperboloid actually **can** be transformed into the lower one and vice-versa: by the time reversal transform $t\to-t$ which is also considered a Lorentz transform in the widest sense (i.e. one that leaves the spacetime metric invariant). However, a Lorentz transform that relates two intertial systems moving with a relative speed of $v$ is a member of the simply connected subgroup that also contains the identity transform, called the proper orthochronous Lorentz group. See [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group). This component does not contain the time reversal transform (nor the space inversion, but that is another story), and hence, is not able not change causality (what came before/after what).

In colloquial terms, a Lorentz transform that you can achieve by burning a rocket from rest (i.e. "connected to identity") will not allow time reversal. Those transforms (called boosts as opposed to mere spatial rotations) can be identified with points on the upper hyperboloid (i.e. final speeds). So, the inability to reverse causality is more or less just expressed by the fact that both hyperboloids cannot be connected by a continuous curve (that starts from the identity, i.e. v=0 for example).